# Can I Put an iPhone 6 and 6s together

Tags: iphone

I’m using an old iPhone 6, and I’m frustrated to see those apps that require iOS 13. Luckily, I have an soaked iPhone 6s (went through the washing machine), which still works except for the camera and soaked display.

Those two iPhones look identical. Will I somehow be able to “combine” these two iPhones into one so that I can use the A9 chip + iPhone 6 hardware + iPhone 6s hardware?

Comment: Is this about will the parts fit or your capabilities?

Comment: @SolarMike of course, will the parts fit. I want to fit the iPhone 6 parts into 6s as much as possible, except the chipset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While there are some parts that are interchangeable, the displays for example, are not - as they have different connectors.

Comment: Yes, I know that; I was looking for a list of what I _can do_ and what I can't.

Comment: There is no complete list of parts that are interchangeable that I know of. You can rule out most of them by comparing the connectors on the mainboards (front camera, display assembly, battery, ...).

Comment: Well, guess I'll have to open them up after all.